# Find all the solutions of the system $AX=B$ if $B$ is the difference between the first and the fourth column of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Let

$$A \sim
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2 &4&1\\
0&0&1&2\\
1&3&1&1\\
0&0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

such that the equivalence is achieved by elementary row transformations. Find all the solutions of the system $AX=B$ if $B$ is the difference between the first and the fourth column of $A$.

I hope I understood this: $$B=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
-2\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$$

But I don't know what should I do here since I don't know what $A$ is exactly...I know $X$ should be a $4$x$1$ matrix and that's about it.

Comment: If you dont know $A$ then as information about $B$ is based on $A$ , then how do you know $B$?that is $B = $ difference of first and fourth column of $A$ and not that of row equivalent matrix

Comment: @BAYMAX Oops, you're right. Ok, I got it from Kanwaljit's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint -

You have A and B.

Solve AX = B.

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2 &4&1\\
0&0&1&2\\
1&3&1&1\\
0&0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
x_4
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
-2\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: See in my edit.

Comment: $X=\begin{pmatrix}
20+19x_4\\
-6-6x_4\\
-2-2x_4\\
x_4\end{pmatrix}$

Is this right?

Comment: Either show me complete steps. Or cross check with following equations to find values. $x_1+2x_2+4x_3+x_4=0, x_3+x_4=-2, x_1+3x_2+x_3+x_4=0$

Comment: @Lewis Yes it is right. Another way to describe it would be the homogenous solutionspace, if that rings bells, here is how it'd be noted: $\begin{pmatrix} 20\\-6\\-2\\0\end{pmatrix}+ lin \begin{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -19\\6\\22\\0\end{pmatrix} \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @WhatAMesh Thanks, never heard of homogenous solutionspace though.